# Gradle - equivalent of test {} configuration block for android

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

Gradle has the test configuration block

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

```

```
apply plugin: 'java' // adds 'test' task

test {
  // enable TestNG support (default is JUnit)
  useTestNG()

  // set a system property for the test JVM(s)
  systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'

  // explicitly include or exclude tests
  include 'org/foo/**'
  exclude 'org/boo/**'

  // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

  // set heap size for the test JVM(s)
  minHeapSize = "128m"
  maxHeapSize = "512m"

  // set JVM arguments for the test JVM(s)
  jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'

  // listen to events in the test execution lifecycle
  beforeTest { descriptor ->
     logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
  }

  // listen to standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s)
  onOutput { descriptor, event ->
     logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
  }
}
```

where one can set all sorts of test configuration (I am mostly interested in the heap size). Is there something similar for android projects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a possibility to add them. Android Gradle plugin has parameter [`testOptions`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.html), which has parameter [`unitTests`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.UnitTestOptions.html), which has option [`all`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html).

So if you write:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
           // apply test parameters
        }
    }
}
```

the tests will be executed with specified parameters.

Comment: that's what I was looking for thanks. I was even already using it but I totally missed it when I started getting out of memory errors when running my tests. I tried a couple more of the parameters found here https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html and they seemed to work